# UWP: Select multiple items of a ListView in code behind

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, windows-10-universal

In my UWP App, I have a `ListView` with `Items`. How can I select `Items` of the `ListView` in code behind?

I have tried to add `Items` to the `SelectedItems` of the `ListView`, or use the `SelectRange()` method of the `ListView`. Nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 2):

> Set SelectedItems of a ListView in CodeBehind

You could use `SelectRange` method to select ListViewItem in code behind. But we need set the  [`SelectionMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.selectionmode?view=winrt-19041) as [`Extended`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewselectionmode?view=winrt-19041) before call SelectRange method (The default is Single selection).

```
TestListView.SelectRange(new ItemIndexRange(0, 3));
```